# javaFX how to add ComboBox to multiple panes

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

im trying to add a comboBox to multiple panes in a project, it gets updated from my model ( im using MVC )

for exampel:

```
ComboBox<String> cmbDepartmentNames = new ComboBox<String>();
public CompanyViewUI(Stage theStage) {

GridPane gpAddNewWorker = new GridPane();
gpAddNewWorker.add(cmbDepartmentNames, 0, 8);

GridPane gpShowDepartmentWorkers = new GridPane();
gpShowDepartmentWorkers.add(cmbDepartmentNames, 0, 3);
}
```

but when im trying to add it to more then one pane it become invisible.

Comment: You can't add the same element in multiple places in the scene graph. (For example, what would methods like  `cmbDepartmentNames.getValue()`, `cmbDepartmentNames.getParent()`, or `cmbDepartmentNames.getLayoutX()` return?) Just create multiple combo boxes.

Comment: Note it doesn't "become invisible". What's happening is the `ComboBox` is being silently removed from its previous parent before being added to its new parent. As already suggested, you need to use multiple `ComboBox` instances that are all backed by the same model.

Comment: ok' i hoped there was a simpler way.